# EC2 instance being terminated after setting up lifecycle hooks

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cdk, amazon-elb

I'm using the AWS CDK to add lifecycle hooks to my ALB in order to be notified by email when an instance gets terminated or when a new one is started. This is what my code looks like:

```
topic = sns.Topic(my_stack, "fleet_changes")
topic_hook = autoscaling_hooktargets.TopicHook(topic)

asg.add_lifecycle_hook(
    'instance-terminating-hook',
    lifecycle_transition=autoscaling.LifecycleTransition.INSTANCE_TERMINATING,
    lifecycle_hook_name="instance-terminating",
    notification_target=topic_hook,
    notification_metadata="INFO: An instance has been terminated"
)

asg.add_lifecycle_hook(
    'instance-launching-hook',
    lifecycle_transition=autoscaling.LifecycleTransition.INSTANCE_LAUNCHING,
    lifecycle_hook_name="instance-launching",
    notification_target=topic_hook,
    notification_metadata="INFO: A new instance has been launched"
)
```

This works fine as I'm indeed getting notifications when an instance is terminated or launched. The problem is that the instances are terminated every hour, and this stops happening when I remove the lifecycle hooks. This is what I see in the ALB events when the hooks are set:

```
At 2024-03-22T17:11:34Z an instance was taken out of service in response to a launch failure.
```

And right after:

```
At 2024-03-22T17:12:35Z an instance was started in response to a difference between desired and actual capacity, increasing the capacity from 1 to 2.
```

I've checked the application logs in Cloudwatch and haven't found anything that would indicate a bug, and there is currently little to no activity on these instances.

Any idea what could be the culprit?

Thank you.

Comment: Some helpful diagnostic steps [here](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/auto-scaling-instance-how-terminated).